# Get a list of latest deposits to a contract address

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, truffle-contract

I have a solidity contract that can receive ETH, how can I write a function in this contract with solidity to get the latest list of transactions that was made to it, for example I want to call this function and it returns the list of deposits/transactions that was made to it, I need to get sender wallet, transaction hash and time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {

    struct Tx {
      uint amountOut;
      uint amountIn;
      uint40 time;
      address receiver;
   }

   mapping(address => Tx[]) userTxs;

    receive() payable external {

        Tx memory newTx = Tx({
            amountOut: 0,
            amountIn: msg.value,
            time: uint40(block.timestamp),
            receiver: address(this)
        });

        userTxs[msg.sender].push(newTx);
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint value) external {
        Tx memory newTx = Tx({
            amountOut: value,
            amountIn: 0,
            time: uint40(block.timestamp),
            receiver: to
        });

        userTxs[address(this)].push(newTx);
        payable(to).transfer(value);
    }

    function getUserTxs(address user) external view returns(Tx[] memory) {
        return userTxs[user];
    }
}
```

Here is a `mapping`, `mapping(address => Tx[]) userTxs;`

where `address` is the `sender`, and `Tx[]` array of `struct Tx`.

You have all the information in `struct Tx` except the hash of the transaction, as it is calculated once the transaction is completed.

Here are a few examples, but I suggest you follow some tutorials and read about solidity, otherwise you'll be blocked at the next step.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, this works perfectly, but I think it would affect the performance, right, because with the passage of time this will become a gigantic array

Comment: welcome @ershad7 ! It depends on what you do with these arrays, if you have to iterate and sum all the values, for example, it will require a lot of computation. 

To be honest I don't think you need to store all this information, you can retrieve all these information (timestamp, hash, etc, from, to, etc) with txId (transactionHash).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are able to do that in EVM. You are able to get latest state, but not transactions.

You will have to query transaction events off-chain and use it there.

Comment: I can't even put them in a mapping array? for example I can add it in the mapping on every deposit and then access them

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you want, thats true.